# Reference enclosing frame in PaintCode expression

Tags: ios, core-graphics, paintcode

I'm trying to use paint code to draw a roundrect with different corner radii. I have nearly everything working by drawing two circles and two roundrects. The problem is I can't make one of the roundrects draw at x offset circle radius have width of "frame.width - circle_radius" - the end effect being it keeps aligned to the right hand edge of the frame.

[image: shapes]

It feels like I should be able to write `frame.width - largeCornerRadius` in an expression editor but PaintCode objects to the frame reference.

That said, i's beginning to feels like I could write this code quicker by hand :-)

Comment: I totally agree. I feel like this is a major issue with paint code as I too can wrote this code faster manually...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to my specific stated question but I have discovered a better way to draw my roundrect as four different rects and turning off the roundrects on the "inner corners:

[image]

As you'd expect the drawing code is much better and it resizes well with the enclosing frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can also :

- use a set of rect, oval or other shapes
- select them and "union" to get one bezier curve for the whole shape
- selection each point (or a set of points) of the resulting bezier and fix springs on each of them as fixed or fluid from the edge of the surrounding frame.

Comment: Union of shapes doesn't resize well - or didn't when I tried. Maybe I didn't have the trick of attaching frames and springs to Bezier points.

Comment: Did you tried to select one or more points on a bezier path and properly set springs ?

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old, but let me show how to achieve this using Springs & Struts.

[image: Resizable rounded rect with different corner radii]

Let’s use 2 circles and 2 rounded rectangle, each having only one corner rounded, just like you have. Once you draw a Frame around these shapes, their Springs & Struct inspector becomes enabled.

[image: Inspector for resizing]

Here you can click each of 6 segments to toggle fixed or flexible dimension for each shape. For *Red Circle*, make flexible only top and right margin (just like on the image above) and for *Blue Circle* the opposite margins (bottom and left). Then for both rectangles make flexible size and fixed margins.

[image: Inspector for rectangle]

For more information, check out our [videos](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/tutorials#dynamic-shapes), [blog](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/power-user-frames), and [documentation](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/documentation/resizing-constraints) on this topic.

<sub>– PaintCode Support</sub>